# Magento2 : I am getting this error when i upload two custom module and css and js file

Tags: magento2, module, javascript, error, css

I am getting this error on my live site as production mode and I uploaded only two custom module and js and css and two overwrite file in our theme.Below share error as warning showing I apply all command upgrad ,deploy,flush,reindex.

> "Warning:
>   include(/home/andrew/public_html/XXXXX.co.uk/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/base/templates/root.phtml):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/andrew/public_html/XXXXX.co.uk/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php
>   on line 327"

Answer (score 1):

Please try by giving 777 permission to generated and var folder

Try after Removing generated folder and var/cahe var/di and var/page_cache and var/view_processed and try it .

Will be better if you try on local first instead of directly on live.

Comment: Thanks for reply but some changes uploading on live site so getting this error .

Comment: Hmm you may check there or may take a complete dump on local and generate there, or may on a staging if u have

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these steps.

1. Change to your Magento Directory
2. `find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +`
3. `find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +`
4. `sudo chown -R <Magento User>:<web server group> .`
5. `chmod u+x bin/magento`
6. Once permission is set deploy your files as Magento user, as this will create the static files without any issue.

   `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Hope this will solve your problem.